# How to cherry-pick from stash in git?

Tags: git, cherry-pick

I am wondering if cherry-picking from stash is possible.

```
git stash save "test cherry-pick from stash"

git cherry-pick stash@{0} # --> Is this possible?
```

I am getting the following error when I tried above command:

```
~/Documents$ git cherry-pick stash@{0}
error: Commit 4590085c1a0d90de897633990f00a14b04405350 is a merge but no -m option was given.
fatal: cherry-pick failed
```

Comment: What do you expect this to do? To git, `cherry-pick` means very specifically applying the changes in just one commit from somewhere (i.e. a different branch), in isolation, to the current branch. If you want to do that for a stash you just `apply` the stash (or `pop` it if you don't need the stash anymore and want to also remove it).

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The problem is that a stash consists of two or three commits. When stashing, the modified working tree is stored in one commit, the index in one commit, and (if using the `--include-untracked` flag) any untracked files in a third commit.

You can see this if you use `gitk --all` and do a stash.

[image]

`stash@{0}` points to the commit that contains the working tree.

You can however cherry-pick from that commit if you do

```
git cherry-pick "stash@{0}" -m 1
```

The reason that `cherry-pick` thinks that the stash is a merge, and thus needs the `-m 1` parameter is that the stash commit has multpile parents, as you can see in the graph.

I am not sure exactly what you want to achieve by cherry-picking. A possible alternative is to create a branch from the stash. Commit changes there and merge them to your current branch.

```
git stash branch stashchanges
git commit -a -m "changes that were stashed"
git checkout master
git merge stashchanges
```

Comment: >>I am not sure exactly what you want to achieve by cherry-picking? --
In my case, a simple merge would be fine by doing stash apply/pop. But, I was wondering if I can cherry-pick few changes from the stashed changes. 

Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Is it possible to do this "git stash branch stashchanges" to pick a specific item (such as #5 in the stash) -- such as something like "git stash@{5} branch stashchanges" ?

Comment: Ah, looks like you can do this via a specific stash commit via `git stash branch stashchanges stash@{1}`

Answer (score 4):

This works for me... git cherry-pick -nm1 stash

YMMV

Answer (score 1):

I was in a situation where I thought I wanted to cherry-pick a stash: I had an old stash that I was inspecting in a tool, but I accidentally dropped it and wanted to revive it.

The solution I found was that you can `git stash apply` with a commit as well as with a stash reference (because `stash@{0}` is just a fancy reference to a commit). This way `stash` is applying the commit and knows how to bring over the content in the stash's merge commits **without creating a merge commit**.

I copied the hash of the "WIP on branchname" commit (where the actual changes live) and passed it to `git stash apply`.

---

Example where `354705f1fa68a840ffa9f60e13b52a3c5d4e3e` is the hash of the stash I was looking at:

```
$ git log --graph --oneline -n4 354705f1fa68a840ffa9f60e13b52a3c5d4e3e

*   354705f1 WIP on room-travel: fe4a0847 Setup room transitions
|\  
| * 72830c5c index on room-travel: fe4a0847 Setup room transitions
|/  
* fe4a0847 Setup room transitions
* 4bed4afe Split per player menu items

$ git stash apply 354705f1fa68a840ffa9f60e13b52a3c5d4e3e
```

Answer (score -7):

I have not done this before. But the man-page on cherry-pick says that it works on commits only.

```
   Given one or more existing commits, apply the change each one introduces,
   recording a new commit for each. This requires your working tree to be
   clean (no modifications from the HEAD commit).
```

Stashing is not a commit and doesn't move HEAD. So, this cannot be done [this is only a guess though]

Comment: Actually, not only is a stash a commit, it is several. But they are often not shown by logging tools. See my answer.