# git stash merge conflict - take stashed version

Tags: git, pull, git-stash

i am wondering how can i take the stashed version of the files.

say i have a file called `foo.c` with some uncommitted changes on master and i would like to update the current branch from remote. Remote has also modified `foo.c`

My current approach is to:

```
stash the current changes on master
git pull --rebase
```

this goes well.

but when i do a:

```
 git stash pop
```

there will be a merge conflict in `foo.c`

so is there a way to take stashed version of `foo.c`?

i.e similar to what can be done with pulling:

```
 git pull -s recursive -X theirs --rebase
```

so what i am looking for is:

```
 git stash pop "-X theirs"
```

that would replace the pulled version of foo.c with the stashed version

tnx for the help

Comment: Have you tried resolving the merge conflicts?

Comment: yes, but i don't like that solution. i would like to replace whatever has been pulled with the stashed version.

looking at the help of git stash, the workflow i am looking for is not described :S

Comment: Ah, yes, I see what you're looking for. Perhaps this can help you? [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861982/how-to-cherry-pick-from-stash-in-git)

Comment: another solution i thought of is to merge the WIP commit that 'git stash' creates. but i think that defeats the reason for using git stash in the first place. as i could just create a dummy branch, pull the remote changes and merge that dummy branch on top of master...

Comment: hmm, @peacewalker that is a possibility, still not a one liner though :)

Comment: What about `git stash branch <newBranch>` and `git cherry-pick <newBranch> -X theirs`?

Comment: if it is a one-off and you know where the conflict happens, just delete that file in the working dir before popping the stash.

Comment: i actually use it quite often. so i guess i'll create a git alias for that using @SevenEleven's suggestion