# git stash clear, except a specific stash

Tags: git, git-stash

Sometimes I use `git stash` to quickly get rid of any spikes or experiments that I think I might want to revisit. A lot of the time, I don't revisit them and my stash list becomes polluted.

I'd like to remove everything in my `git stash` except one specific stash.

Example: my `git stash list` looks like this:

```
stash@{0}: On test-branch: try something
stash@{1}: WIP on spiked-branch: 2cc4751 another spike attempt
stash@{2}: On master: 2cc4751 experimental refactoring
stash@{3}: WIP on spiked-branch: 3ccfc4d first spike attempt
```

I'd like to just keep `stash@{2}`. Is there an easy way to do this?

I know I can achieve my results by taking the following steps:

```
git reset --hard origin/master #=> ensure I have clean branch
git stash pop stash@{2} #=> put stash on current branch
git stash clear #=> clear all stashes
git stash #=> re-stash what I popped in step 2
```

This seems tedious. Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: This may be your solution. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16861982/how-to-cherry-pick-from-stash-in-git

Comment: @AnthonyC Hmm I don't think so. I'm not trying to run `git cherry-pick`, the whole stash should remain in tact and in my `git stash list`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to make it less tedious would be to put the commands in a script. Here I have done so, with a few modifications to make it more robust:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

git reset --hard HEAD && git stash pop stash@{$1} && git stash clear && git stash
```

Changes from your version:

1. Use `HEAD` instead of a branch name, so that you don't unexpectedly move a branch pointer.
2. Select which stash to pop based on the first argument.
3. Use `&&` to chain the commands together, because if one fails, you probably don't want to continue to the next.

You could then call it as e.g.:

```
mystashclear.sh 2
```

Where you want to save stash number 2.

Alternatively, you could just use an alias:

```
git alias.clear-except "! git reset --hard HEAD && git stash pop stash@{$1} && git stash clear && git stash"
```

And again you can use it as:

```
git clear-except 2
```

Comment: This is a great idea. Thanks!